# Как суммировать отрезки времени

Tags: java

Программа моделирует работу некоторой системы за разные последовательные промежутки времени. Она должна прекращаться работу, когда суммарное время превысит некоторое значение.
Теперь вопрос: используя какую библиотеку можно считать накапливаемое время?

Я вот использую Period (JodaTime), но что-то не пойму, как его можно увеличивать.. Можно ли сложить 2 Period?

Comment: Исправьте формулировку вопроса пожалуйста. Несколько раз надо прочитать первое предложение, чтобы понять что к чему.

Уточните также о каком классе Period идет речь. Я подозреваю, что речь идет о библиотеке Joda-Time. Но, во-первых, я могу ошибаться. Во-вторых, кто-то другой может вообще не понять, о чем идет речь.

Comment: @a_gura , исправил.   А что Вы можете посоветовать тут?

Comment: Может, [это](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/Period.html#plus%28org.joda.time.ReadablePeriod%29)?

Comment: Вот черт) Его использовал, не получалось, т.к. результат ничего не присваивал... спасибо!   
Кажется надо поспать..)

Comment: @Stas0n: популярная ошибка, я тоже много раз натыкался на неё в своём коде :) Компиляторам пора бы выдавать warning.

Comment: @VladD, и, ведь, смотришь на косяк и упорное не видишь его.. эх)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У класса Pеriod есть метод [plus](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/Period.html#plus%28org.joda.time.ReadablePeriod%29), который в качестве параметра принимает период для сложения.

Библиотека Joda-Time также содержит класс [Duration](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/key_duration.html), метод plus которого позволяет складывать как два экземпляра типа Duration, так и увеличивать один экземпляр Duration на указанное кол-во единиц.

Comment: Добавлю ещё о разнице между Period и Duration: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2654107/276994